# excel webservice http header

Tags: excel, api, http-headers

I am wondering if there is a way to include http header in excel WEBSERVICE function.
I am trying to use an API witch need a Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN :

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer  ac004670-8f66-340a-b4d0-312b585d8cb3' 'https://api.insee.fr/metadonnees/V1/codes/nafr2/sousClasse/84.11Z'
```